# ParseError while trying to grab tickers

Tags: python, pandas, shutil, python-os, yfinance

I am trying to get my program to run.
All the packages I am using are up to date.

I am expecting the program to print stock tickers that I have chosen.

However, I am getting a lot of errors I can't seem to understand the errors I am getting.

I have tried changing mktcap_min and mktcap_max to smaller values but to no avail.

I'm also not sure if my file & folder paths are correct syntax.

I have also looked up similar errors people were having but I haven't been able to implement the solutions I've seen into my own code.

The error messages I get when I run the program in Command Prompt are as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop\Classes\testPrograms\poker.py", line 51, in <module>
    tickers = gt.get_tickers_filtered(mktcap_min = 150000, mktcap_max = 10000000, sectors = None)
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\get_all_tickers\get_tickers.py", line 84, in get_tickers_filtered
    tickers_list.extend(__exchange2list_filtered(exchange, mktcap_min=mktcap_min, mktcap_max=mktcap_max, sectors=sectors))
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\get_all_tickers\get_tickers.py", line 145, in __exchange2list_filtered
    df = __exchange2df(exchange)
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\get_all_tickers\get_tickers.py", line 134, in __exchange2df
    df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=",")
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 586, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 488, in _read
    return parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1047, in read
    index, columns, col_dict = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py", line 223, in read
    chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 801, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 857, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 843, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1925, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 5, saw 47
```

From my very basic level of understanding, could I possibly have a memory problem? How can I remedy this situation and get my program to run without these errors?

This is the all the code for the program:

```
import yfinance as yf, pandas as pd, shutil, os
from get_all_tickers import get_tickers as gt

tickers = gt.get_tickers_filtered(mktcap_min = 150000, mktcap_max = 10000000, sectors = None)
print("the amount of stocks chosen to observe: " + str(len(tickers)))

shutil.rmtree(r"C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop\Classes\testPrograms\pokerStorage")
os.mkdir(r"C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop\Classes\testPrograms\pokerStorage")

Stock_Failure = 0
Stocks_Not_Imported = 0

i=0
while (i < len(tickers)) and (Amount_of_API_Calls < 1800):
    try:
        stock = tickers[i]
        temp = yf.Ticker(str(stock))
        Hist_data = temp.history(period="max")
        Hist_data.to_csv(r"C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop\Classes\testPrograms\pokerStorage\historicalData.csv")
        time.sleep(2)
        Amount_of_API_Calls += 1
        Stock_Failure = 0
        i += 1

    except ValueError:
        print("Yahoo Finance Back-end Error, Attempting to Fix")

        if Stock_Failure > 5:
            i+=1
            Stocks_Not_Imported += 1
            Amount_of_API_Calls += 1
            Stock_Failure += 1
            
print("The amount of stocks successfully imported: " + str(i - Stocks_Not_Imported))
```

Comment: It does seem like this is your fault; there is an open ticket related to this on the `get_all_tickers` github page. Check it out here: https://github.com/shilewenuw/get_all_tickers/issues/12 It also appear to have a simple solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nasdaq API got updated, which this package is based on. See the [open issue on github](https://github.com/shilewenuw/get_all_tickers/issues/12).

The solution (provided by [github user Possums](https://github.com/Possums))

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'authority': 'api.nasdaq.com',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36',
    'origin': 'https://www.nasdaq.com',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://www.nasdaq.com/',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

params = (
    ('tableonly', 'true'),
    ('limit', '25'),
    ('offset', '0'),
    ('download', 'true'),
)

r = requests.get('https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/stocks', headers=headers, params=params)
data = r.json()['data']
df = pd.DataFrame(data['rows'], columns=data['headers'])
```

Comment: In the open issue on GitHub you linked, someone updated the get_tickers.py file to have the updated API. I ended up just replacing the old file with the new one. Thanks so much for the help.